# how to add current location like in picture in flutter using geo location

Tags: flutter

https://github.com/kardotinambunan12/tinambunan/blob/master/Screenshot%20from%202021-07-08%2017-03-51.png.

if I click the gps_fixed icon then my location will be displayed in the textfield.

I'm still writing code for the template. but the logic part I don't understand.

template:

```
 Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14.0),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "sampel",

              fillColor: whiteColor,
              // enabled:false,
              prefixIcon: Icon(
                Icons.add_location_outlined,
                color: primaryColor,
              ),
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed),
                color: primaryColor,
              ),
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: primaryColor),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 2,
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
          child: CustomRaiseButton(
            "Clock In",
            color: primaryColor,
            textColor: whiteColor,
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Have you wrote any code?

Comment: I'm still writing code for the template. but the logic part I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the location name from its coordinate using [Geocoding API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder) which is well implemented by a plugin called [geocoding](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)

it is as simple as

```
import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart';

List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(52.2165157, 6.9437819);
```